# Update is too slow

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Updating is way too slow:

```
//class for Database
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('/database.db');
    }
}

//new db - Object
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
    echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}
```

This code updates the database and gives me begin_time and length:

```
//BEGIN
$db->exec('BEGIN;');

//prepare update:
$smt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET username = :username, full_name = :full_name, is_private = :is_private, is_follower = 1, updated_on = :time, was_follower = NULL WHERE user_id = :usernameId");
//bind parameter
$smt2->bindParam(':usernameId', $usernameId);
$smt2->bindParam(':username', $username);
$smt2->bindParam(':full_name', $full_name);
$smt2->bindParam(':is_private', $is_private);
$smt2->bindParam(':time', $time);

//Prepare second update
$smt3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET followed_on = IfNull(followed_on, :time) WHERE user_id = :usernameId");
//bind parameter
$smt3->bindParam(':usernameId', $usernameId);
$smt3->bindParam(':time', $time);

try {
    echo "start\n";
    $time_begin = time();
    echo $time_begin;
    
    //LOOP
    foreach ($followers as $follower) {
        $usernameId = $follower->getUsernameId();
        $username = $follower->getUsername();
        $full_name = $follower->getFullName();
        $ProfilPicUrl = $follower->getProfilePicUrl();
        $is_private = $follower->isPrivate();
        //muss 0 sein, aber ist im mom einfach nur '' bei false.
        if(strcmp($is_private, 1) !== 0){
            $is_private = 0;
        }
        
        $time = time();
        //Function, which returns rows, how often an entry exists in db (can only be 0 or 1)
        $existence = item_exists($db, 'users', 'user_id', $usernameId);
        if($existence)
        {
            //EXECUTE first update
            $smt2->execute();
            if(!$smt2){
                echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
            }
            
            //EXECUTE second update
            $smt3->execute();
            if(!$smt3){
                echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
            }
        }
    }
    //COMMIT
    $db->exec('COMMIT;');

    //TIME
    $time_diff = time() - $time_begin;
    echo "END: ". $time_diff . "\n";
    
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I already use "BEGIN" and "COMMIT" and "prepare". But for an array with 10300 entries it still takes 173 seconds. Where I insert an array with 100.000 entries that took 8 seconds! What makes the update statement in this code so slow?

I merged the two update statements into one:

```
$smt2 = $db->prepare("EXPLAIN UPDATE users SET followed_on = IfNull(followed_on, :time), username = :username, full_name = :full_name, is_private = :is_private, is_follower = 1, updated_on = :time, was_follower = NULL WHERE user_id = :usernameId");
```

It still takes 87 seconds.

"EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN" :

> 0|0|0|SCAN TABLE users

Comment: Try running a `EXPLAIN UPDATE users SET username = <rest of query here>` and make sure your query plan uses an Index to lookup the user.